Drawing a centerline through a polygon using Python libraries
I want to draw a CENTERLINE through a polygon using Python libraries. The current tools and libraries provide ways to draw the "Medial Axis" BUT I want the centerline to go all the way to the surface of the polygon.
Here is an example of what I want


What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed

The newest alpha of pygeoops has support to generate centerlines like that via the extend=True parameter of pygeoops.centerline. You can install the alpha version using pip install pygeoops==0.5.0a1
